# Query efficiency of timestamp-partitioned tables using CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

Tags: sql, postgresql, timestamp, partitioning

Given the following table partitioning under PostgreSQL 9.0.3:

```
CREATE TABLE records (
  ts TIMESTAMP,
  ...
);

CREATE TABLE records_2010 (
  CHECK (ts >= '2010-01-01 00:00:00' AND ts < '2011-01-01 00:00:00')
) INHERITS (records);

CREATE TABLE records_2011 (
  CHECK (ts >= '2011-01-01 00:00:00' AND ts < '2012-01-01 00:00:00')
) INHERITS (records);
```

I expected the following SELECT queries to have the same EXPLAINed plan, consulting only "records" and "records_2011", but they differ:

```
BEGIN;
-- Assume CURRENT_TIMESTAMP is 9 a.m. on 5 March 2011
SELECT * FROM records WHERE ts >= '2011-03-05 09:00:00'; -- scans 2 tables
SELECT * FROM records WHERE ts >= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;     -- scans all 3 tables
COMMIT;
```

Given that CURRENT_TIMESTAMP returns a constant value for the duration of its enclosing transactions, **why doesn't the query with CURRENT_TIMESTAMP take advantage of Postgres' partitioning and only scan two tables?**

**UPDATE:**

This isn't possible right now, but it is recognized as an area to improve.  PostgreSQL 9.1 may [address this behavior in the query executor](http://archives.postgresql.org/pgsql-performance/2010-03/msg00080.php).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you run a query for the first time, PostgreSQL determines a query plan.  This is an expensive operation and the result is cached.  So the query has to work for future executions as well.

Your first query will never need `records_2010`, regardless of when you run it.

But the second query uses a variable `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`.  The optimizer does not know that time can only increase, and generates a plan that will work for any value of `ts`.  That means it has to look in all three tables.

Comment: yes, but why doesn't the query engine substitute in constant values for "transactionally IMMUTABLE" functions like CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, and only thereafter turn to query planning?  It doesn't matter if CURRENT_TIMESTAMP increases or not -- every call to inside one transaction returns the same, independent value.
Is there something about CURRENT_TIMESTAMP that makes this infeasible?  (IMHO it'd always be preferable to sub in constant values before query planning for statements which might benefit from partitioning's "constraint exclusion" mechanism.)

Comment: @pilcrow: The query plan will be reused for future transactions as well, maybe days or weeks later.  The reason that values are not substituted is that query planning is expensive.  Creating a plan for every version of `select * from orders where id = :orderId` would kill performance.

Comment: on this data set, one *partition-aware* plan per query is much faster than re-using the same partition-unaware plan.  (And, just to be clear, we're talking about "constant-folding" a function call, rather than :placeholders per se.)
In any case, it looks like [9.1 will accomplish what I want](http://tinyurl.com/5ttopaq)

Comment: Sadly PG9.2 still has the same problem. It can't use partitions efficiently as soon as its not an explicit constant. Like if you use in a trigger function with SELECT INTO myResult * FROM myPartitionnedTable WHERE partitionKeyField = NEW.partitionKeyField... it scans all the partitions :-( It would be my #1 wish for PG9.4 (9.3 doesn't seem to address this) if the query plan could be more partition aware.